# Question about proving singleton set has outer measure zero

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, lebesgue-measure, outer-measure

> Proof:
>
> $$\{x\}\subset \left(x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$
>
> $$\{x\}\subset \cap_{n=1}^\infty
>  \left(x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$
>   where $$\cap_{n=1}^\infty
>  \left(x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ is a $G_\delta$ set
>
> and hence $$\lambda^*(\{x\}) \le \inf_{n \in
>  \mathbb{N}}l\left(x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}\right)=\inf_{n \in
>  \mathbb{N}} \frac{2}{n}=0.$$

I don't understand why

> $$\{x\}\subset \left(x-\frac{1}{n},x+\frac{1}{n}\right)$$ for all $n
>  \in \mathbb{N}$

How do I know this is true?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just says
$$x-\frac1n<x<x+\frac1n$$
which is equivalent to
$$-\frac1n<0<\frac1n$$
for all $n\in\mathbb N$.
You believe that’s true, right?

Answer (score 0):

Because, for each natural $n$, $x-\frac1n<x<x+\frac1n$. Therefore, $x\in\left(x-\frac1n,x+\frac1n\right)$, which is equivalent to asserting that $\{x\}\subset\left(x-\frac1n,x+\frac1n\right)$.